# Quarkus OIDC session cookie limit

Tags: cookies, openid-connect, quarkus

during upgrade of my app to quarkus 3 I stumbled over the 4kB cookie limit in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0#session-cookie-is-encrypted-by-default and the solution proposals below.

1. Splitting cookies for id / access token / refresh token doesn't have any effect
2. My app does need the roles from inside the token, so I can't cut them off
3. Registering a custom TokenStateManager with DB-access seems to be a lot of effort.
4. The option to not encrypt the cookie seems to be the obvious solution to me, in TLS communication the cookies in the http headers should be encrypted anyway. But then why does quarkus now introduce this feature? Am I missing something important?

Comment: ASP.NET Core for example encrypts all the data, and if the content is more than 4000 bytes, then it splits the data into chunks (multiple cookies) where each one is max 4kb. I think cookies should be encrypted and secure, as cookies might get tampered with in surprising ways (browser plugins....)

Comment: Right, it is now encrypted by default to address some reported concerns, though indeed, if it is HTTPS then it can be still quite secure and hard to have them leaked. If ID token does not contain anything really sensitive then it is still integrity protected. Refresh token can only be used by Quarkus. I'm surprised splitting does not help. Just for the test, what happens if you set the strategy to `id-token` only, see https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-code-flow-authentication#token-state-manager ? See also a token-state-manager section below about a DB option

Comment: Thanks for the input, that was my gap: The browser itself could be evil.

Setting the strategy to `id-refresh-tokens` or `id-token` results in

    INFO: HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : %s
    UserInfo is required but DefaultTokenStateManager is configured to not keep the access token

Comment: I wonder why splitting didn't help as well. Is there a way to log the cookie before the log warning?

Comment: @kraeftbraeu, re that Userinfo problem, yes, without the access token it can't be acquired, so Quarkus fails early, not a browser issue. if it is more than 4K then it will be a massive message, I can update the code to print the size.

Comment: @kraeftbraeu, FYI, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/37785, that may help, in meantime, please consider turning off the encryption just to keep going with the migration. As far as the ID token is concerned, can you try to find out what its actual size is before the linked issue gets resolved ? For ex, try the hybrid application type and login into your provider from Quarkus Dev UI: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-dev-services#dev-ui-all-oidc-providers ? If it works ten SPA will show the ID token

Comment: Hi @SergeyBeryozkin, thanks, with encryption turned off I was able to finalize the migration. Some more Hibernate SqlResultSetMappings need to be tested, but that should be it.

Testing in dev mode could be little tricky, my keycloak doesn't allow localhost as redirect URL, for local startup I'm using https://quarkus.io/guides/security-properties. But I can see the request headers my browser sends after redirect from keycloak. The q_session cookie header size is 3128b, including the "q_session=" to be accurate.

Comment: The idea of splitting or chunking cookies sound promising. I guess chunking needs to be done in quarkus code base, but the quarkus docs sound like splitting should already work. But then why don't I see any difference? Can I override https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/oidc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/runtime/CodeAuthenticationMechanism.java#L964 somehow to add loggings for tests?

Comment: Thanks @kraeftbraeu for checking the cookie header size. Can you please give it another try with splitting the session cookie with `quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.split-tokens=true` ? If a combined unencrypted cookie length is just about 3K, then given that Keycloak returns 3 tokens, ID, access and refresh one, all in JWT format, you should get encrypted `q_session`, `q_session_at` and `q_session_rt` cookies comfortably meeting the 4K limit. Please check again and let me know what cookie headers you see after the split.

Comment: Hi Sergey, with these properties

`quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.encryption-required=false`
`quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.split-tokens=true`

I get these cookie sizes:
q_session:  3073b
q_session_at: 41b
q_session_rt: 41b

Probably these 3073b encrypted still are over 4kB size.

Comment: But I just decoded my cookie and realized the size derives from my huge list of roles in integration environment. In production this should not be an issue, I just need to reduce my roles. In the long term I'm still interested in a quarkus solution able to handle bigger cookies and I would like to help finding it. The goal of your PR seems to be using a cookie-size-efficient encryption algorithm, I can check the result, please just let me know the quarkus version to use.

Comment: Hi @kraeftbraeu, OK, thanks. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/37816 is about skipping the extra key generation which will save 120 or more bytes, that might work with a 3073b size - please watch that PR, it will likely be merged now only in 2024 Jan. But I agree that if the token is 5K for whatever prod-level reasons, it won't help if they have to be encrypted. We offer an OOB DB token manager - but on the stateless path the only other option is to follow a hint from the 1st comment here, split it into chunks automatically, worth investigating, thanks

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/37836

Comment: @kraeftbraeu FYI, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/37891

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could post some cookie item sizes (both encrypted and unencrypted) to better illustrate your problem. Meanwhile here are some things that can influence behaviour.

**ENCRYPTION**

Auth cookies should be encrypted, and usually a symmetric algorithm like AES256-GCM is used, with encrypted bytes encoded as base 64. This should increase size by around 30% but not radically. Whereas if encrypted JWTs are being issued, in a 5 part JWE format, that might explain a big size difference.

**OPAQUE TOKENS**

This is a great way to reduce cookie sizes, when supported, without the need to maintain your own token stores in each app. Access and refresh tokens issued to internet clients are then small values like UUIDs, whose encrypted size remains small.

**TOKEN SIGNING ALGORITHMS**

You can reduce size with a different algorithm sometimes. Eg RS256 is often used but is not the most secure, and also produces large JWT signatures. Out of interest EdDSA is a very secure option that produces small signatures.

**LIMIT COOKIE SENDING**

As well as splitting tokens, see if you can configure different cookie paths like this, to reduce the size of the overall cookie header. Each request should then use less than 4KB of total cookie size:

- Access token path: /
- Refresh token path: /refresh
- ID token path: /claims

It is a good security practice to limit cookie sending also. Eg the refresh or ID token are not needed if the browser calls APIs.

**COOKIE LIMITS**

Unless you have very large JWTs, where individual cookies exceed 4KB, you should be OK in the main desktop and mobile browsers I think. Post details of specific browsers with problems otherwise.

In recent testing I've found JWTs in cookies, where each is < 4KB, should work fine in current mobile and desktop browsers. That is, the max cookie size per domain can exceed 4KB. Some HTTP servers, such as NGINX, have a default total limit of 4KB though, that can need extending.